# npm can't be found when I run ionic start

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I'm getting the error

```
> npm.cmd i
[ERROR] Command not found: npm
```

when I run ionic start.
npm -v and node -v both give me results of latest versions, and I have my environment variable set. I ran ionic start last month and it worked completely fine, but it just isn't working now, please help.

[image]

Comment: What is npm.cmd? does  'npm i' also fail? If npm -v works that means your path is set properly.

Comment: I guess it's the command that ```ionic start``` is trying to run after I set all of the options like the name, framework etc. npm i does not fail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389575/how-to-run-npm-cmd